# Chinese characters with multiple unicode representations

Tags: unicode, cjk, chinese-locale

Some Chinese characters have multiple Unicode representations. For example, although the characters 金 and 金 are usually rendered the same, they actually have different underlying unicodes (see https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+91D1 and https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+F90A#UNC_DB). Evidently, the site [www.compart.com](http://www.compart.com) knows about the links between these two Unicodes as there's a link to the U+91D1 page in the U+F90A page.

Is there a public database where I can query these kinds of correspondences between Unicode characters that are actually the "same"?

Comment: Of course? The unicode website covers all of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [Unicode Normalization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

*Is there a public database where I can query these kinds of correspondences between Unicode characters that are actually the "same"?* Yes, there is [Unicode Character Database](https://www.unicode.org/ucd/); pay your attention to [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt): technically a `csv` file without header line ([fields described here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UnicodeData.txt)). We are interested in the 5th field (`Decomposition_Type` `Decomposition_Mapping`):

> (5) This field contains both values, with the type in angle brackets.
> The decomposition mappings exactly match the decomposition mappings
> published with the character names in the Unicode Standard. For more
> information, see [Character Decomposition Mappings](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Character_Decomposition_Mappings).

Search the file *manually* or semi-automatic: [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) in Windows or equivalent bash command (Linux): [`grep`](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) for your code point `91d1`:

```
findstr /I /R "\<91d1\>" "\Utils\CodePages\UnicodeData.txt"
```

> ```
> 2FA6;KANGXI RADICAL GOLD;So;0;ON;<compat> 91D1;;;;N;;;;;
> 322E;PARENTHESIZED IDEOGRAPH METAL;So;0;L;<compat> 0028 91D1 0029;;;;N;;;;;
> 328E;CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH METAL;So;0;L;<circle> 91D1;;;;N;;;;;
> F90A;CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-F90A;Lo;0;L;91D1;;;;N;;;;;
> ```

The characters found above are

- `⾦` (U+2FA6,  *Kangxi Radical Gold*)
- `㊎` (U+328E,  *Circled Ideograph Metal*)
- `金` (U+F90A,  *CJK Compatibility Ideograph-F90a*)
- `㈮` (U+322E,  *Parenthesized Ideograph Metal*)
- `金` (U+91D1,  *CJK Ideograph*) (missing in above `findstr`  output as it's *hidden* in the *CJK Ideograph* block, code points `4E00`..`9FFF`).

The following Python script could enlighten some aspects of normalization…

```
import sys
from unicodedata import normalize

def encodeuni(s):
    '''
    Returns input string encoded to escape sequences as in a string literal.
    Output is similar to
      str(s.encode('unicode_escape')).lstrip('b').strip("'").replace('\\\\','\\');
    but even every ASCII character is encoded as a \\xNN escape sequence
    (except a space character). For instance: 
    
    s = 'A á ř ';
    encodeuni(s);       # '\\x41 \\xe1 \\u0159 \\U0001f308'     while 
    str(s.encode('unicode_escape')).lstrip('b').strip("'").replace('\\\\','\\');
    #                   #    'A \\xe1 \\u0159 \\U0001f308'
    '''
    def encodechar(ch):
        ordch = ord(ch)
        return ( ch                if ordch == 0x20   else 
                 f"\\x{ordch:02x}" if ordch <= 0xFF   else
                 f"\\u{ordch:04x}" if ordch <= 0xFFFF else
                 f"\\U{ordch:08x}" )
                 
    return ''.join([encodechar(ch) for ch in s]) 

if len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] != '':
    letters = (' '.join(
    [sys.argv[i] for i in range(1,len(sys.argv))])).strip()
    # .\SO\59979037.py  ÅÅÅ
else:
    letters = '\u212B \u00C5 \u0041\u030A \U0001f308'
    #          \u212B                     Å Angstrom Sign
    #                 \u00C5              Å Latin Capital Letter A With Ring Above
    #                        \u0041       A Latin Capital Letter A
    #                              \u030A ̊  Combining Ring Above
    #                                     \U0001f308  Rainbow

print('\t'.join( ['raw' ,
                  letters.ljust(10),
                  str(len(letters)),
                  encodeuni(letters),'\n']))
for form in ['NFC','NFKC','NFD','NFKD']:
    letnorm = normalize(form, letters)
    print( '\t'.join( [form,
                      letnorm.ljust(10),
                      str(len(letnorm)),
                      encodeuni(letnorm)]))
```

**Output**: `encodeuni.py ⾦㊎金金㈮`

```
raw     ⾦㊎金金㈮      5       \u2fa6\u328e\uf90a\u91d1\u322e

NFC     ⾦㊎金金㈮      5       \u2fa6\u328e\u91d1\u91d1\u322e
NFKC    金金金金(金)    7       \u91d1\u91d1\u91d1\u91d1\x28\u91d1\x29
NFD     ⾦㊎金金㈮      5       \u2fa6\u328e\u91d1\u91d1\u322e
NFKD    金金金金(金)    7       \u91d1\u91d1\u91d1\u91d1\x28\u91d1\x29
```

**Further resources** (required reading): [Unicode® Technical Reports](https://www.unicode.org/reports/)